# Oracle SELECT WHERE value exists or doesn't exist

Tags: sql, oracle, select, where-clause

I have 3 tables; `CASES`, `USERS` and `USER_META`. For this issue you need to know that the `USER_META` table has 3 columns; `user_id`, `meta_key` and `meta_value`

Each user is associated with many `CASES` and each `USER` is associated with many `USER_META`

My current query is like this

```
SELECT CASES.*, USERS.*, USER_META.*
FROM CASES
JOIN USERS ON USERS."user_id" = CASES."user_id"
JOIN USER_META ON USER_META_"user_id" = USERS."user_id"
```

The problem with this approach is that each USER has **A LOT** of USER_META so my result set has too many rows. How can I rewrite this query so that I can select only the USER_META where the USER_META."meta_key" is equal to a certain value **yet still get the result if they do not have this USER_META."meta_key" set yet**

For example:

```
SELECT CASES.*, USERS.*, USER_META.*
FROM CASES
JOIN USERS ON USERS."user_id" = CASES."user_id"
JOIN USER_META ON USER_META_"user_id" = USERS."user_id"
WHERE USER_META."meta_key" = 'my_key'
```

This would work great but not all users have a value of "my_key" in the "meta_key" column and we still need to view their CASE. For users that do not have the "meta_key" the result should just return the CASE and USER columns.

How can I rewrite this query so it gets the result for both users with this meta_key and without?

Thanks, I hope this makes sense.

Comment: `SELECT CASES.*, USERS.*, USER_META.*` -- the resultset will include duplicated columns, which isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT CASES.*, USERS.*, USER_META.*
FROM CASES
JOIN USERS ON USERS."user_id" = CASES."user_id"
LEFT JOIN USER_META ON USER_META."user_id" = USERS."user_id" AND USER_META."meta_key" = ?
```

Comment: Great, it looks like I was putting the WHERE/AND clause in the wrong spot. Placing that logic in the JOIN statement is the solution. THANKS!

Comment: @Mike: The key has 2 parts: placing the logic in the JOIN and making it an (outer) `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use OUTER JOIN with the table that may have no results. In Oracle, use (+) near to the field name of the join sentence with this table. This link may help you: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries006.htm